# Does qsort use heap memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, qsort

Using the stdlib implementation of `qsort()` in VS2008.

Does this implementation of `qsort()` use memory on the heap? Or is only stack-based memory used?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::sort()`?

Comment: That's fine too. Question still stands though. I don't need a fast sort, just one that does not use heap memory.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, VC++ comes with source for the runtime library (except for most of the floating point routines), but you might need to check certain boxes during install/reinstall to get it. If you want to know details of the implementation you can usually find the answer there pretty readily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quicksort is an inplace sorting algorithm. Except for the space on the runtime stack for the recursive calls it doesn't use any memory.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `qsort()` isn't required to use the Quicksort algorithm - though I think that most use some variant of it. (For example, glibc's docs mention: "The implementation of qsort in this library might not be an in-place sort and might thereby use an extra amount of memory to store the array")

Answer (score 2):

What it uses and what it does not use is an implementation detail. The specification of the language does not provide any answer to this question.

What can be said though is that there's *no reason* for a reasonable `qsort` implementation to use dynamic memory. A properly implemented recursion plan in `qsort` will never require recursion depth that is greater than the `log2` of the maximum array size on the given platform. Which means, for example, that on a flat memory platform  the recursion depth will not exceed the "bitness" of the platform (e.g. it is no deeper than 32 on a 32-bit platform). This in turn means that `qsort` easily permits an entirely stack-based implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/0_9_1/libc/stdlib/qsort.c) and [here](http://www.umcs.maine.edu/~chaw/200801/capstone/n/qsort.c) it does not allocate memory on the heap at all.

Comment: Linking to two other implementation doesn't answer this question about the VC++ implementation..